# Using List<>.Contains() with different type

Tags: c#

I have a generic-ed list of a custom type

```
List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();
```

I've overridden the .Equals of MyType so that it works if you compare a string or a MyType to it. My question is - is there a way of using List.Contains(string) if the List only contains MyType?

I realise there are other ways I can do it (such as creating a MyType object there and then instead of the string), but is there a way of doing it without having to extend List?

Comment: Just curiosity: why do you need that?

Comment: I'm refactoring code which once used a list of string instead, and I don't want to have to break large amounts of code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use linq:

```
bool hasSugar = list.Any(i => i.Equals("sugar"));
```

Comment: The question was on  `Contains`

Comment: Hmm, this looks like it could work pretty easily. Can I also use 'Remove' in a similar manner? I never used linq much.

Comment: @Tigran: Yes, I know the question was on `Contains` - but linqs `Any` is a built in workaround, so I suggested it.

Comment: @Haedrian Yes, `list.RemoveAll(i => i.Equals("sugar"))`

Answer (score 3):

Haedrian,

Could Linq solve this for you? Below in my example 'MyType' is a list of Integers yet I'm able to do a 'Contains' on a string value and get back a filtered list.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

List<int> list = new List<int>();

List<int> sList = (from s in list
where s.ToString().Contains("1")
select s).ToList();
```

I hope that's helpful. You should search for Linq examples, it's very powerful.

Comment: Errr, I had this window open in "edit" for a while before posting. If this doesn't add anything to Anders example, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Contains can be used with custom IEquatable if you have implemented the interface for your custom types. You can either implement a common IEquatable interface for a specific type eg. they both have a **unique** int value which can be used as id.
In this case you can use IEquatable , and in the implementation body:

```
class MyType1 : IEquatable<int>

bool IEqutabale<int>.Equals(int other)
{
    if (Id == other) return true;
    return false;
}
```

then you can compare as follows:

```
if (Type1List.Cast<IEquatable<int>>().Contains(type2Obj.Id)
{
   //write your code here
}
```

Your other option is to implement **direct** Equality between both types. 
That is :

```
class MyType1 : IEquatable<MyType2>

bool IEquatable<MyType2>.IEquals(MyType2 other)
{
     //write equality logic here
}
```

Then you can compare as follows:

```
if(Type1List.Cast<IEquatable<MyType2>>().Contains(type2Object))
{
    //write your code here
}
```